# Publishing ASP.NET MVC 4 Application to server IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

In the office we have a server on the 'N' drive and we use IIS6 to create folders on our current domain which are then used as test directories for website building. Our website's domain is 'www.example.com' and sometimes, when I want to create a test environment for a new website, I'll go into IIS6, create a new directory e.g. 'test', make into into an application and then upload the website files and navigate to 'www.example.com/test' to find the website that I've built.

I've recently finished building a new website using ASP.NET MVC 4 platform, but I'm having a bit of trouble actually publishing it to a new directory that I've created e.g. 'test2'. I'm currently trying to publish it by right licking the project in VS 2012 and clicking publish before electing to publish the project using the 'file system' method and selecting the directory I wish to public to 'test2'. After clicking okay, the files are published okay but when navigating to 'www.example.com/test2', I get a 403 error message.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, so if anyone has any idea of what's going wrong I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure to convert the folder to an application in IIS manager?

Comment: Hi Travis, yes I definitely made the directory into an application. It had a cog next to it

Comment: Am I doing it correctly by publishing to the file system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe IIS 6 supports MVC